# product list not appears in magento search result

Tags: magento, search, product

Magento search engine find results for the search query but doesn't display them [image]

update:
i found this error in system log.

2014-12-25T11:44:14+00:00 CRIT (2): Not valid template file:frontend/base/default/template/timer/product/list.phtml

Comment: Try enabling error report and check what is the error

Comment: Have you found an issue?